# How to parse a UTC date time to user's locale with modern java.time?

Tags: datetime, kotlin

I get the following string from the API, which is in UTC, however it has no timezone definition in it. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

I would like to parse it into dateTime and convert it to user's locale and then display it as `h:mm a`. I would like to use the modern java.time please.

So I came up with this:

```
val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val endDateString = "2020-12-21 20:32:39"

val odtInstanceAtOffset = OffsetDateTime.parse(endDateString, dateTimeFormatter)
```

^ It crashes here

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-12-21 20:32:39'
> could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from
> TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2020-12-21T20:32:39 of type
> java.time.format.Parsed

```
val odtInstanceAtUTC = odtInstanceAtOffset.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

So not sure if this is the right way. I assume at this point if I could convert that string into a UTC date time instance I could continue like this:

```
val localDate: LocalDate = utcDatetime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a")
val displayDate: String = formatter.format(localDate)
```

Correct?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the zone information to the `DateTimeFormatter` and then you can parse the String using the `DateTimeFormatter`. The result of this is an `TemporalAccessor` object which can then be formatted to the format you require. Like so:

```kotlin
val endDateString = "2020-12-21 20:32:39"
    
val utcDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)

val localDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("hh:mm a")
    .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    
val displayDate = utcDateTimeFormatter.parse(endDateString) { temporal ->
    localDateTimeFormatter.format(temporal)
}
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/6goM5m6Bl)

Comment: Perhaps this is a new question, but since this is pure String conversion and I still don't have a date object. How can I compare the date against the current date? `if(todayDate.after(endDate) { ... }`

Comment: You can check previous editions to my answer. In the first one, I have initialised a variable with an object of `Instant`. You will find suitable methods in `Instant` for comparison.